# SharePoint 13 Approval Workflow. Can not select a template

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval

I am unable to select a workflow template, and therefore unable to click Next

I see "Disposition Approval" and "three-State" but can't select either of them.

I enabled and disabled Workflows in the Site Settings.

[image: Workflow Settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you have done it in Manage Site Features,then you need to try it from **Site Collection Feature** by Activating/Deactivating Workflow Feature.

Let me know whether it solves your problem.

Thanks

Comment: I do not have access to Site Collection Feature, only to my site